# Docker Copy Command fails

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, docker-desktop, docker-build

I am new to Docker , while running the Docker file

**My Docker file**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.0-preview1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base 
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.100-preview1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /DineshVisualStudio/Autofac-interceptor/AutofacModule/Autofac.interface.ConcactFactory
COPY Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory.csproj project/
WORKDIR /Autofac-interceptor/project
RUN dotnet restore
COPY /Autofac.interface.Concactfactory .
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory.exe"]
```

When running `docker build -t myappfactory .` it's failing. I tried many combinations for the path in COPY command but without any luck.

**I am using Visual Studio 2017 and had installed Docker Tools too**

This is my folder structure
[My folder structure with the code having docker file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNVJN.png)

when running `docker build -t autofacinterface .` I'm getting an Error saying:

`failed to create file . System cannot find the file specified.`

I am using Cmd to build the docker from my current working .csproj folder.

```
D:\DineshVisualStudio\Autofac-Interceptor\AutofacModule\Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory>docker build -t autofacinterfaceconcatfactory .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/15 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.0-preview1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
---> 2df5940c47f7
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /app
---> Using cache
---> f4d2190d9b44
Step 3/15 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.100-preview1-sdk AS build
---> af242cb10bf0
Step 4/15 : WORKDIR /DineshVisualStudio/Autofac- 
interceptor/AutofacModule/Autofac.interface.ConcactFactory
---> Using cache
---> dbf15787395b
Step 5/15 : COPY /Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory.csproj project/
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker- 
builder138146052\COPY: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**after @Mike suggestion I am getting this issue:**

```
D:\DineshVisualStudio\Autofac-Interceptor\AutofacModule\Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory>docker build -t myappfact .
Step 6/15 : WORKDIR /Autofac-interceptor/project
Step 7/15 : RUN dotnet restore
---> Running in 9e91df3e68a3
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current 
working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: after Mikes suggestion I modified the docker file . Now I am getting an issue
    {    D:\DineshVisualStudio\Autofac- 
         Interceptor\AutofacModule\Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory>docker build 
        -t myappfact .
        Step 6/15 : WORKDIR /Autofac-interceptor/project
          Step 7/15 : RUN dotnet restore
         ---> Running in 9e91df3e68a3
        MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current 
       working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
       The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the leading `/` in `COPY /Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory.csproj`. The source file(s) are relative to current working directory, and you've already called `WORKDIR` previously.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: I modified as you suggested. Now I am stuck at the last bit

D:\DineshVisualStudio\Autofac-Interceptor\AutofacModule\Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory>docker build -t myappfact .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  18.98MB

Step 6/15 : WORKDIR /Autofac-interceptor/project
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60441dcd4f55
Step 7/15 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 9e91df3e68a3
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Your `WORKDIR` probably is off. In Step 6 I would give it the fully qualified path: `WORKDIR /DineshVisualStudio/Autofac-interceptor/AutofacModule/Autofac.interface.ConcactFactory/project`. Also note that Step 8 will likely have the same issue with leading `/` character.

Comment: In my case I have multiple folders having csproj file and are having dependency. So Will this Docker file work?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with .NET development and project structures, but in general you should set your Docker Build context to the highest level common directory of all projects. Then make sure any command that references a path is relative to any `WORKDIR` directive you set. You could also try removeing all `WORKDIR` directives and make sure every path you reference is relative to the build context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 5/15 : COPY COPY
```

Do you have the word `COPY` twice in a row in your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The command "*COPY /Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory.csproj project/*" failed. I recommend you read more about the command COPY [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy). Use the command "*COPY . .*" if you run *docker build* from the folder "D:\DineshVisualStudio\Autofac-     Interceptor\AutofacModule\Autofac.Interface.ConcatFactory".